# Add a condition to th:text on thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, spring, thymeleaf

i have a table on my html file where it's populated like this:

```
<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left">First Name</th>
            <th class="text-left">Last Name</th>
            <th class="text-left">Status</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
            <td class="text-left" th:text="${user.firstname}"></td>
            <td class="text-left" th:text="${user.lastname}"></td>
            <td class="text-left" th:text="${user.status}"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

the problem is that for status i have two conditions : Online and Offline , what i want to do is if status=='online' change the th:text color to green and when status=='offline' change it to red. I don't know if there's a way to do this with thymeleaf or will i have to use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use the `th:classappend`? You could define two CSS classes with your rules (color:red; or color:green;) and assign the right class depending on the condition:

```
<td class="text-left" th:text="${user.firstname}" th:classappend="${isOnline} ? onlineCSSClass : offlineCSSClass"></td>
```

p.s. I supposed that `isOnline` is a variable set to true/false depending if it is online or offline

Comment: actually status is a string not a boolean

Comment: just define in your java code a bool variable like:
`boolean isOnline = status == "online"; `
and use that boolean inside the conditional classappend